# Send camera video stream to the server using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, video-streaming

I am developing an application for Android, iOS and Windows.

I want to know if there is an api to send camera stream to server using RTSP or HTTP or TCP?

Comment: actually this is WebRTC-based peer-to-peer streaming, but may help https://components.xamarin.com/view/icelinkcommunity

Comment: It is limited to non-commercial applications and to LAN networks. it stops after 30 seconds in WAN networks.